# update column with other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I use `PL/SQL`, This is my table

```
 a   |    b    |    c   |   d
-----------------------------
 1   |    1    |    2   |
 1   |    2    |    2   |
 1   |    2    |    2   |
 1   |    3    |    2   |
 1   |    3    |    2   | 
 2   |    2    |    2   |
 2   |    4    |    2   |
 2   |    5    |    1   |
```

And it will become to

```
 a   |    b    |    c   |   d
-----------------------------
 1   |    1    |    2   |  1
 1   |    2    |    2   |  2
 1   |    2    |    2   |  2
 1   |    3    |    2   |  3
 1   |    3    |    2   |  3
 2   |    2    |    2   |  1
 2   |    4    |    2   |  2
 2   |    5    |    1   |
```

`d` column will start from `1` and then plus 1

if `b` column start change,

and if `a` column become different, the `d` column will repeat start from `1`.

I want to update `d` column with `c` equal `2`.

I know how to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY )`, but that I have two column relationship. I have no idea.

How to do that? Thanks appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, data manipulations in Oracle updates are a pain.

This does what you want:

```
update table t
    set d = (select count(distinct b)
             from table t2
             where t2.a = t.a and
                   t2.b <= t.b
            ) ;
```

In a `select` query, you can do this with `dense_rank()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sicne you cannot use windowed functions in a `SET` clause, I believe you will need to use a nested query to get your new values for d.  The following should work for you:

```
UPDATE T
SET    T.d = D.d
FROM Table1 T
-- Join on a subquery to get the new 'd' values:
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT a, b, c, -- Get the identifiers for this row
         -- Get the new value for d
        dense_rank() over (partition by a 
                           order by b) as d
  FROM Table1
) D -- Map the new 'd' values back to the appropriate row
ON T.a = D.a and T.b = D.b AND T.c = D.c
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0be47/1/0)